# binding watch and $timeout order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've come across the code of a component that set the HTML: `$scope.htmlContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(content)`, then, in a `$timeout` calls a function that will find an element inside that content using `$element.find('.stuff')...`

That code is inside a `$scope.$watch` of the `$onInit` function.

My question is: are we 100% certain that the DOM element for the content will be rendered before the `$element.find`? Is there a better approach?

Minimum code to understand:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

  angular.module('mymodule').component('exampleComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'path/template.html',
    bindings: { content: '<' },
    controller: ExampleComponentCtrl
  });

  function ExampleComponentCtrl($element, $sce, $scope, $timeout) {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $sce.valueOf(self.content);
      }, function() {
        // irrevelant stuff that creates variable content that contains html code

        $scope.htmlContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(content);

        // use $timeout to wait for the inner HTML to be injected
        // so that we can find `.file-link` elements
        $timeout(function() { $element.find('.stuff').each... });
      });
    };
  }
)();
```

HTML template:

```
<pre ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></pre>
```

Comment: can you share the complete code?

Comment: @GauravSrivastava almost complete code

Comment: Maybe you can use a directive with a ``compile`` function and access the DOM in the controller's ``$onInit``?

Comment: I think @LeonardoChaia is right, but i am sure your solution is good too because timeout will be triggered in next digest which is after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what actually this component should achieve... Have a look at this:

```
function ExampleComponentCtrl($element, $scope, $compile) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.$onInit = function() {
    };

    vm.$onChanges = function() {
      if (vm.content) {
        $element.empty();
        $element.append($compile(vm.content)($scope)); // if you html does not contain angular, compile is not required
        console.log('Found element: ' + $element.find('p')[0].id);
      }
    };
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3BSwabSDtfuE0q69NnP4?p=preview